# How to access variables created outside an Rmpi requests?

Tags: r, mpi

I am trying to use Rmpi for parallel processing for the first time. When calling a self-made function using the mpi.apply command, the code can't seem to access variables created prior to the execution of the command. Here is an example:

```
library(Rmpi)
mpi.spawn.Rslaves()

df1 <- data.frame("x" = 1:2, "y" = 1:2)
df2 <- data.frame("x" = 2:3, "y" = 2:3)
df3 <- data.frame("x" = 3:4, "y" = 3:4)
df4 <- data.frame("x" = 4:5, "y" = 4:5)

fun <- function(x) {
  input <- get(paste0("df", x)) 
  return(input)
}

array <- 1:4
MPIresults <- mpi.apply(array, fun)
```

And I get the following error messages:

```
<simpleError in get(paste0("df", x)): object 'df1' not found>
<simpleError in get(paste0("df", x)): object 'df2' not found>
<simpleError in get(paste0("df", x)): object 'df3' not found>
<simpleError in get(paste0("df", x)): object 'df4' not found>
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here? Should I be using another MPI command instead of "mpi.apply" that considers prior variables?

Thanks!

Comment: You can specify the `envir` in `get`

Comment: I get the same error message. Can't seem to access df1-4.